# How to Figure out the bounds of a Surface for Surface Integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I can't seem to figure out the bounds of a given surface. The problem statement is to approximate the mass of the homogeneous lamina that has the shape of given surface S and density function:
$$S = 8-x-4y, z\ge 0, x\ge 0, y\ge 0; \rho = x$$

I found $\vec{r}(u,v)=<u, v, 8-u-4v>$. When I sketched out the surface (which is a plane), I seemed to have found the bounds $0 \le u \le 8$ and $ 0 \le v \le 8-\frac{x}{4}$.

Finding the cross product of the partial derivatives in respect to $u$ and $v$ I get the vector $<1, 4, 1>$ and it's magnitude is $\sqrt{18}$.

So, $\rho(\vec{r}(u,v)) = u$ and $|\vec{r}_u \times \vec{r}_v| = \sqrt{18}$.

Setting up my double integral, $$\int_{0}^{8}\int_{0}^{8-\frac{x}{4}}u\sqrt{18}dvdu$$

After simplifying, I get $\frac{640}{3}\sqrt{18}$ which is obviously wrong.

Did I go setting up the bounds of the surface incorrectly, or am I just applying the integration wrong?

Comment: A couple of questions - (1) Why is it "obviously" wrong? (2) Where did you get your bounds from? The original question had no restrictions on $x,y$ so it is standard to assume the plane goes on forever. (3) What is "$S$" in $S=\cdots$? That equation doesn't make any sense at all. If $S$ is the surface you care about, then $S$ is a set and cannot be a quantity involved in an equation of real numbers.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I just assumed wrong (and Cengage deemed it wrong) because the way I set up everything was probably incorrect. And as for the bounds I guessed, which is why my question was how to set up the bounds. When I sketched it out, I used the level curves way. So when z = 0, it's minimum value, meaning we are on the xy-plane now for the sketch. When y is 0, x will be 8 (x = 8 - 4y), and solving for y, y = 8 - x/4. So for the bounds of x it is between 0 and 8, and then the bounds for y is from y = 0 to y = 8 - x/4.

Comment: Did you see my updated comment? There is a third question. Also I see your edit - Without the assumption that we are in the first quadrant, the bounds would have just been $-\infty$ to $\infty$ because a plane goes on forever. That was an important detail to include for that reason.

Comment: Lastly you only made one mistake - $$\frac{8-x}{4} \neq 8 - \frac{x}{4}$$ Fix that and you should have the right answer.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes I apologize, I realized I omitted the bounds - was typing it out quickly in frustration. It has been a rough few problems. Also, funnily enough I just realized I divided incorrectly just before seeing your comment. Will be attempting it now.

Comment: @NinadMunshi That was my mistake, I got it correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness' sake, from the comments we clarified that the surface of integration is the portion of that plane located in the first octant only. All of your work up to this point is correct, the only problem is the final bound where

$$y = \frac{8-x}{4} = 2 - \frac{x}{4} \neq 8 - \frac{x}{4}$$

which gives us the integral

$$\sqrt{18}\int_0^8\int_0^{2-\frac{u}{4}}u\:dv\:du = 3\sqrt{2}\int_0^82u-\frac{u^2}{4}\:du = \boxed{64\sqrt{2}}$$